# Galaxy rotation curve and galaxy mass

Tags: astrophysics, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

Is there a relation between the saturation velocity of the galaxy rotation curve and the luminous mass of the galaxy? To clarify the question, if one were to plot a scatter plot with the x-axis as the luminous mass of a galaxy (or luminous mass density of a galaxy), and y-axis as the saturation velocity of the galaxy rotation curve, is there any definite relation? Note: In this scatter-plot, each point represents a galaxy.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tully%E2%80%93Fisher_relation

Comment: @shawn_halayka. Thanks. This answers.